# How can I tell new Python to use the old print

Tags: python, portability

The print function's syntax has been changed in newer versions of python. The problem is that at home, I have the newer version of python while at office the old one. How can I have the same program run on both the newer and old python versions?

Comment: To make it more clear: You cannot use the old print in Python 3.X. You can only use the new print in Python 2.6+ as described in the answers.

Comment: @Trilarion You summed it perfectly :-) I think you should convert [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104398/how-can-i-tell-new-python-to-use-the-old-print#comment36487488_19104398) to an answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using iPython/ Jupyter, run

```
%autocall 1
```

After that, you can use

```
print "yo"
```

like in Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

Many 2 vs 3 porting issues are [covered well here](http://python3porting.com/).

In general, I think it's more hassle than it's worth to try to keep a single `.py` file that runs under both versions.  But if you want to try, that link shows usable workarounds.

While it's true that Python 2 supports, for example,

```
print("abc", 3)
```

the results aren't the same:  in Python 2 that prints the **tuple** `('abc', 3)`.  And Python 2's `print` doesn't support Python 3's optional keyword arguments at all (like `file=`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use new print syntax on older version of python.

Comment: Except for the trailing comma.

Comment: @MarkRansom Nope.  Add `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of a file to get the new syntax *exactly*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new `print` function in old scripts like this:

```
# This line goes at the top of the file ...
from __future__ import print_function

# And then you can use the new-style print function anywhere
print("hello")
```